# Identify a short story wherein a time-travel uses classified ads to search for other time-travelers

Tags: story-identification

In the story, the time traveler travels to the sixties, I believe, and posts an ad somewhere along the lines of:

"Remember Reaganomics? VCRs? Perestroika? Call me at KL-123."

Obviously, only another time traveler who'd experienced the eighties would recognize those terms ('VCRs' may be misremembered, but you get the point). I'm pretty sure about the "Reaganomics" term, which will date its writing to most likely in the eighties, certainly no earlier than 1981.

Comment: [Time Travel ads, eh?](http://www.backwoodshome.com/articles2/silveira125.html)

Comment: It looks like Mike already has the one you're looking for, but a similar situation arises in John Barnes' *Kaleidoscope Century*. Note that the book is probably not appropriate for youngsters--the protagonist is very much a Bad Person.

Comment: @thedaian - I KNOW! That stupid ad killed the viability of a Google search.

Comment: @thedaian, that sounds suspiciously like the ad from Safety Not Guaranteed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[*Replay*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_%28novel%29) by Ken Grimwood. The actual line is:

> Do you remember Watergate? Lady Di? The shuttle disaster? The
>   Ayatollah? *Rocky*? *Flashdance*? If so, you're not alone. Contact P.O. Box 1988, New York, N.Y. 10001

Comment: I loved this 1988 book. If you remember the epilogue, there was a _future_ replayer, Peter Skjoren, who would be replaying 1988-2017. If Ken Grimwood hadn't died of a heart attack (I guess he is replaying now), maybe we would have gotten a sequel next year...